# Three Conditional Formatting Rules per Cell in Row B- Need help copying for entire table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I've been using conditional formatting for years, but I've hit an unexpected snag.

I currently have the rules set to:

- Formula: =$A$2=0, format = cell color red, applies to =$B$2:$B$2
- Formula: =$A$2=1, format = cell color yellow, applies to =$B$2:$B$2
- Formula: =$A$2=2, format = cell color green, applies to =$B$2:$B$2

Super simple conditional formatting. The problem is when I drag cell B2 down to the rest of the end of the table (B13), it copies the formatting based on the original formula; so the rules become:

- Formula: =$A$**2**=0, format = cell color red, applies to =$B$2:$B$13
- Formula: =$A$**2**=1, format = cell color yellow, applies to =$B$2:$B$13
- Formula: =$A$**2**=2, format = cell color green, applies to =$B$2:$B$13

What I need is the formula to change as well:

- Formula: =$A$**3**=0, format = cell color red, applies to =$B$**3**:$B$**3**
- Formula: =$A$**4**=0, format = cell color red, applies to =$B$**4**:$B$**4**
- Formula: =$A$**5**=0, format = cell color red, applies to =$B$**5**:$B$**5**

And so on to reflect each of the three rules.

I've not used macros or vba in Excel before, but I tried to write code for conditional formatting based off of various threads and sites, but I can't get it right. I am proficient in Access, but conditional formatting and working with cells is new territory for me.

Is there an easy way to create the rules for each line, or am I destined to rewrite all three rules by hand for the entire table?

Comment: Remove the $ before the number so ```$A2``` $ locks the reference. You actually don't need the $ before the column either since you are going vertically not horizontally. I'm not sure you can increment the value you are checking for though.

Comment: Remove the `$` from the row: `=$A2`

Comment: Change absolute references to relative: `=A2=0, format = cell color red, applies to =B2:B13` to be changed from`=$A$2=0, format = cell color red, applies to =$B$2:$B$13`. If you do not need the reference for the same $B$2:$B$13 range. If yes, change only A2 instead of $A$2

Comment: Thank you all! I never knew what the money sign was for, I just know that excel will add it.